# Carbon Dating - Same age but different original radioactive nuclide left

Tags: radioactivity, half-life

2 same trees but diferent sizes fell 2000 years ago. We are trying to find their age using carbon dating. So my understanding is that their age will come to be same approx 2000 years but percentage of original C-14 left in each would be different as decay depends on the orginal C-14 and that would be different in both the tress due to different sizes. Is that correct understanding?

Comment: While the total amount of C14 may differ, the relative amount of C14:C12 does not.

Comment: @Jon Custer So , it means that percentage of original C-14 left in each would be same.?